# Agregar estilos CSS a el-select durante el keyDown y KeyUp | Element UI

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un el-select

**Estilos cuando pasa el mause:**

```
.el-select-dropdown__item:hover{
  background-color:#999bb8;
  color: white;

}
```

Esta parte funciona correctamente , pero cuando utilizo las feclas arriba y abajo sobre las opciones de el-select , **quisiera tener los mismo estilos con las flechas**

https://element.eleme.io/#/es/component/select

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ElementUI](https://element.eleme.io/#/es) no utiliza la pseudo clase `:hover` para agregar este estilo, agrega una clase `.hover` utilizando javascript para que se aplique el estilo sin importar si es por medio de hover o por medio de las flechas del teclado.
intenta el siguiente codigo:

```
in.el-select-dropdown__item.hover {
  background-color:#999bb8;
  color: white;
}
```